# Changing vhosts to work with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, wamp, vhosts

If I have the main Symfony2 folder in c:\wamp\www\myproject\Symfony\web, what do I need to change in my vhosts (or elsewhere) so I can just point to `http://localhost/myproject` to view my application?

I am using WAMP on Windows 8.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Symfony. The wamp documentation will point you to the file you need to change.

Comment: I am reading http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html but it is not clear to me what file it is referring to in the Apache section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reed this steps and you will configure your virtuals Hosts.. This has nothing to do with Symfony....

http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp